# troubles in extracting data from facebook graph c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm working on a program that exports all user public data but the graph is making troubles,i made an app and got all the permissions (the extended profile properties permissions, and extended permissions) to generate the access token which i use to extract data, what confuses me is that some profiles extract the hole data some other don't even if it appears in the section.

example:

attempting to export me/ exported all the data i have sports education hometown etc..
attempting to export friend/ exported public data + sports and no education even tho he got education in the about section and it appears to public or friends 
attempting to extract me/subscribers showed 12 subscribers which is right
attempting to extract friend/subscribers showed 12 of 20 even tho the subscribers appears as 20 in the subscribers section
i'm using the following command:

```
 var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookLikes>(fb.Get(txtUserName.Text + "/likes").ToString());
```

i hope you understand the idea, thanks for the help

okay here the problem with a live test:
i tried the following on the tool you stated:

```
blazzzin/?access_token
```

the result was:

```
{
  "id": "100001748944712",
  "name": "Ethan 'blaze' Parker",
  "first_name": "Ethan",
  "middle_name": "'blaze'",
  "last_name": "Parker",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/blazzzin",
  "birthday": "02/20",
  "hometown": {
    "id": "102161913158207",
    "name": "Delhi, India"
  },
  "quotes": "You're what you eat. Really? I am an Apple then.",
  "sports": [
    {
      "id": "102173226491776",
      "name": "Soccer"
    },
    {
      "id": "112285278784684",
      "name": "Badminton"
    }
  ],
  "favorite_teams": [
    {
      "id": "138570342846531",
      "name": "WWE Nexus"
    },
    {
      "id": "136759993012177",
      "name": "Delhi Daredevils"
    },
    {
      "id": "42884080673",
      "name": "Uruguay"
    },
    {
      "id": "365383271987",
      "name": "Chelsea FC"
    },
    {
      "id": "151170071595882",
      "name": "Best of wwe"
    },
    {
      "id": "166496596733768",
      "name": "WWE World"
    },
    {
      "id": "19221964237",
      "name": "ECW"
    },
    {
      "id": "31695961025",
      "name": "Impact Wrestling"
    },
    {
      "id": "5985827589",
      "name": "Fnatic"
    },
    {
      "id": "61630257716",
      "name": "University of Cincinnati Bearcats"
    },
    {
      "id": "44027083759",
      "name": "Cincinnati Reds"
    },
    {
      "id": "323348924370835",
      "name": "Wrestling Memes"
    },
    {
      "id": "127573517418762",
      "name": "Veer Marathi"
    },
    {
      "id": "208056762558521",
      "name": "Team Razer"
    },
    {
      "id": "228215007216138",
      "name": "The awkward moment when you go to grab someone sexy and headbutt the mirror"
    },
    {
      "id": "200933243299323",
      "name": "If she's never seen Arsenal win a trophy, she's too young for you Bro"
    },
    {
      "id": "189411184456673",
      "name": "Sanfransisco Giants"
    },
    {
      "id": "210487655659656",
      "name": "Team Bring It vs Team Cenation"
    },
    {
      "id": "146995142049876",
      "name": "Like IF the First THNG You Do WheN You WAKE UP is ROll OVR &CHeCK UR Phone"
    },
    {
      "id": "111507918902981",
      "name": "• WWE Universe | Tunisian Page •"
    }
  ],
  "favorite_athletes": [
    {
      "id": "104023396299513",
      "name": "Andrew Flintoff"
    },
    {
      "id": "545498258812287",
      "name": "Luke Wright"
    },
    {
      "id": "111832475503333",
      "name": "Michael Schumaker"
    },
    {
      "id": "110393655686342",
      "name": "Eddie Alvarez MMA"
    },
    {
      "id": "112941715451427",
      "name": "Maryse"
    },
    {
      "id": "344128252278047",
      "name": "Sachin Tendulkar"
    },
    {
      "id": "179559748752616",
      "name": "Maryse"
    },
    {
      "id": "52911737290",
      "name": "Doraemon"
    },
    {
      "id": "14320933255",
      "name": "Andrew Flintoff"
    },
    {
      "id": "81221197163",
      "name": "Cristiano Ronaldo"
    },
    {
      "id": "136644946409767",
      "name": "Mahmoud's charity run from Melbourne to Sydney"
    },
    {
      "id": "42888741032",
      "name": "R-Truth - WWE Universe"
    },
    {
      "id": "203402113048458",
      "name": "Abby Marie Johnson WBFF Bikini 2014 Competitor"
    },
    {
      "id": "270759951686",
      "name": "JASON DAVID FRANK - Official Fan Page"
    },
    {
      "id": "110336188978264",
      "name": "AJStyles.Org"
    },
    {
      "id": "8707340185",
      "name": "Edge - WWE Universe"
    },
    {
      "id": "298344150293189",
      "name": "Fandango - WWE"
    },
    {
      "id": "195569370462754",
      "name": "William Regal: A Tribute To An Underrated Legend"
    },
    {
      "id": "173741199368967",
      "name": "Steve Moriarty"
    },
    {
      "id": "12714756642",
      "name": "Fedor Emelianenko"
    },
    {
      "id": "212481352152206",
      "name": "Arkan Taha Fitness"
    },
    {
      "id": "160505357316902",
      "name": "Lexi Thompson"
    },
    {
      "id": "10035000964",
      "name": "The Great Khali - WWE Universe"
    },
    {
      "id": "176063032413299",
      "name": "Leo Messi"
    },
    {
      "id": "65920772679",
      "name": "Maria Sharapova"
    },
    {
      "id": "226790007363705",
      "name": "Divas - WWE UNiVERSE"
    },
    {
      "id": "175535596516",
      "name": "Sabine Lisicki"
    },
    {
      "id": "415063578542561",
      "name": "Eddie Guerrero"
    },
    {
      "id": "157829220895967",
      "name": "Kaitlyn - WWE Universe"
    },
    {
      "id": "122046337858201",
      "name": "WWE Maryse Ouellet"
    },
    {
      "id": "185950250927",
      "name": "Brock Lesnar"
    },
    {
      "id": "8164128018",
      "name": "Layla - WWE Universe"
    },
    {
      "id": "110108465743414",
      "name": "PUSH EVAN BOURNE"
    },
    {
      "id": "115647961808394",
      "name": "We love Evan Bourne"
    },
    {
      "id": "105683519512165",
      "name": "Sin Cara - WWE"
    },
    {
      "id": "125557244171559",
      "name": "Rikishi"
    },
    {
      "id": "8457822873",
      "name": "CM Punk - WWE Universe"
    }
  ],
  "inspirational_people": [
    {
      "id": "17774451468",
      "name": "Mr. Bean"
    },
    {
      "id": "9972312428",
      "name": "The Miz - WWE Universe"
    },
    {
      "id": "103107176396108",
      "name": "CM Punk"
    },
    {
      "id": "10392229299",
      "name": "Gurbaksh Chahal"
    }
  ],
  "education": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "424030284317485",
        "name": "HarvardX"
      },
      "year": {
        "id": "120960561375312",
        "name": "2013"
      },
      "concentration": [
        {
          "id": "108146682539885",
          "name": "Justice"
        }
      ],
      "type": "College"
    },
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "102052863223529",
        "name": "TGC Animation and Multimedia"
      },
      "year": {
        "id": "120960561375312",
        "name": "2013"
      },
      "concentration": [
        {
          "id": "199849176695930",
          "name": "Web Design & Development"
        },
        {
          "id": "109803049037749",
          "name": "Graphic Design"
        }
      ],
      "type": "College"
    }
  ],
  "gender": "male",
  "relationship_status": "In a relationship",
  "significant_other": {
    "name": "Hailey Hayden",
    "id": "100006853479540"
  },
  "website": "http://www.varunpuri.me

",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "languages": [
    {
      "id": "106059522759137",
      "name": "English"
    },
    {
      "id": "113301478683221",
      "name": "American English"
    },
    {
      "id": "112969428713061",
      "name": "Hindi"
    },
    {
      "id": "110343528993409",
      "name": "Spanish"
    },
    {
      "id": "105606752807048",
      "name": "Punjabi"
    },
    {
      "id": "107672419256005",
      "name": "Dutch"
    }
  ],
  "updated_time": "2014-01-05T16:49:55+0000",
  "username": "blazzzin"
}
```

i tried it on another friend and the friend have all the data public example work and education  (i can see them in the about section)

```
khalil.bsaibes/?access_token
```

the result was:

```
{
  "id": "806750229",
  "name": "Khalil G. Bsaibes",
  "first_name": "Khalil",
  "middle_name": "G.",
  "last_name": "Bsaibes",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/khalil.bsaibes",
  "location": {
    "id": "106188806084417",
    "name": "Beirut, Lebanon"
  },
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "updated_time": "2014-01-12T09:39:29+0000",
  "username": "khalil.bsaibes"
}
```

so can you explain me what's happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What if the user whose information you are trying to access hasn't made some of his information public?

You can use the below tool to debug by putting the access token and your query and seeing what is the returned json. If it returns only 12 subscribers, then you should check the permission, if it returns 20 then recheck your code and parsing method..

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: there is no errors it doesn't extract all the data, sorry i'm not at work now i don't have the program neither any templates :/

Comment: this means that the other user has not authorized your app or given you the permissions, that's why you can't access his information. In your application you should be requesting these permissions first, then you can use them.

Comment: i requested me to access to friend abouts using friends_about_me isn't that enough ?